# PCAP header types

Tags: c, networking, pcap

Does anyone know the Ethertype number of UDP and TCP? I know IPv4 is 0x0800 and IPv6 are 0x86dd. I'm writing a program that gives me information about a packet based on the type of packet it is.

Comment: You are at a wrong abstraction layer.

Comment: IANA maintains some number lists. The EtherType numbers are found in _[IEEE 802 Numbers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ieee-802-numbers/ieee-802-numbers.xhtml)_, while the IP protocol numbers are found in _[Protocol Numbers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml)_, and the transport protocol (e.g. TCP and UDP) numbers are found in _[Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ethernet frame has three parts source,destination MAC address and Ethertypes.
Ethertypes show us how Layer-2 interacts with Layer-3 in the OSI model. As you look up the model, At Layer-3, within IPv4 there is a protocol field to determine if it is TCP, UDP, ICMP or something else. At Layer-4, within TCP and UDP, we have the port to determine which application should handle the packet.

So TCP and UDP doesn't have Ethertypes, instead they have protocol numbers. The following are the protocol numbers for UDP and TCP :

*0x11 for User Datagram Protocol (UDP)*

*0x06 for Transfer Control Protocol (TCP)*

[Reference](https://peteccde.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/understanding-ethertype/)

Comment: This is not an ethertype. It's a protocol number in an IPvX header.

Comment: perfect thank you. Just doing further research and yeah I noticed those are actually within the IP header, the tutorial still didn't show the numbers that represent the protocols though, so thank you, this helps a lot.

Comment: @Mike1982 I am happy to hear it helped.

Comment: @Billa Even if it helped and accepted, it doesn't make the answer correct. It is not. Please fix it. These numbers are *not* EtherType.

Answer (score 0):

EtherType is a type of a *Network Layer*, which is the layer 3 on the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), and is found as a field of the Ethernet frame (The Data link layer, number 2). TCP and UDP are the *Transport Layer*, which is one layer above the network layer. So there is no EtherType for these protocols. These are usually implemented on top of IP layer (IPv4 or IPv6) and have a Protocol type number, which is shorter and contained within the IPvX header instead.